# Create a SIP / VoIP phone routing application

Tags: c#, .net, sip, voip

At the office we have a hosted VoIP telecom system. We use SIP / VoIP phones and recently we have been playing with some SIP clients on our iPhones. Connecting with these 'other clients' works fine and that made me think; can I do some programming on this? 
I'm not really interested in making a SIP client / soft phone, but more something like a 'soft receptionist'.

Is there a library I can use in a .NET ( + code examples), which enables me to create an application that can see who's calling and redirect calls depending on that incoming phone number?

Or, when there is some OOTB software available I'd like to hear about that too.

Comment: Shameless plug but you could take a look at sipsorcery.com. It will allow you to do lots of SIP signalling functions with IronRuby dialplans. And if you want to go deeper the code behind the service is all open source and written in C# http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if such libraries exist, but if you're only redirecting you'd only have to parse and slightly adjust the SIP messages (plain text), you don't have to route the audio (I've done this in PHP once). SIP is quite well documented.

Comment: Okay, only having to parse and adjust some messages sounds good :) But, where to start with doing this? Seems to me that i still have to start with writing some app that receives these messages?

Comment: I bet you have already found the SIP rfc ( http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt), SIP usually uses UDP as transport. You could download a softphone (X-Lite (http://www.counterpath.net/x-lite.html) for instance) and have it 'call' your UDP-listening application, and you'll receive your first SIP spam (the protocol automatically retransfers messages if no response was provided).